# Unable to call sync function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a webapp. In one part of it, I want to transfer js variable to php to sync user data saved locally with that on the internet.

This is the HTML Code:

```
<li><a onclick="sync();">Sync</a></li>
```

This is the JavaScript function:

```
function sync(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","sync.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var tags = localStorage.getItem("tags");
var data = "tags="+tags;
xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

This is the php part:

```
<?php
echo $tags;
console.log($tags);
return $tags;
?>
```

When I click on the sync button, this is the error I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sync is not defined (index):103
onclick
```

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: You most likely defined said function in a child scope rather than globally.

Comment: try to add `sync();` inside the js file where function located just to make sure the error is not from the function and see the console error log what it say

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` sorry for you bro...

Comment: Well where is function sync defined in your page's markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1) keep the below mentioned js code in the same file in which you are calling the sync() function between

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

2) The js code is as follows:

```
function sync(){
console.log("hi");

}
```

If you get the "hi" in the console log, replace the above code with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely defined said function in a child scope rather than globally. A quick fix would be to add it to the window:

```
(function () { // this is an example of what could cause it to be in a child scope
    function sync () {
        ...
    }
    window.sync = sync;
})();
```

but i'd suggest instead moving away from inline event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the function `sync` does not exist in the global scope at the time you click the anchor.

`onclick` and other event attributes are generally considered bad practice, you should use event listeners from your JavaScript code like so:

```
var button = document.getElementById("sync");
button.addEventListener("click", sync, false);
```

***NOTE:** It is important you initialise this script after the DOM has loaded, the simplest way is to put it just before you close the body tag.*

And alter your HTML like so:

```
<li><a href="#" id="button">Sync</a></li>
```

You need to make sure your function uses `Event.preventDefault` so that it does not trigger a refresh of the browser window, for example:

```
function sync(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

  // Rest of your function
}
```

More on event listeners can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

There are some browser compatibility issues especially with old versions of Internet Explorer that you must be aware of, there are shims provided on that page.